# C++ Windows Thread Won't Exit

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

In the code below, a thread is initiated that calls a network sniffer whose output is displayed on a console.  After 1500 milliseconds, I expected the thread to terminate, but it doesn't.  Can you provide insight on my error?  Thanks in advance for your help.

```
unsigned int __stdcall mythreadB(void* data)
{

    // declare
    char            *Directory = "c:/Program Files/Wireshark";
    int             Ret = 0;
    string          Tshark_Command = "";

    Ret = _chdir(Directory);
    Tshark_Command = "tshark\ -V -B 5";
    system(Tshark_Command.c_str());

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    HANDLE          myhandleB;
    myhandleB = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(0, 0, &mythreadB, 0, 0, 0);
    WaitForSingleObjectEx(myhandleB, 1500,false);
    CloseHandle(myhandleB);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To start with, you should check what each and every system call returns. If it returns an error you should [check what that error is](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The thread has to wait for "other-app.exe" to finish, otherwise it doesn't get past `system`. Probably other-app is getting stuck.

You can see the problem if you put instead `system("notepad.exe");`

One solution is to use `CreateProcess`

```
unsigned int __stdcall mythreadB(void* data)
{
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = { 0 };
    STARTUPINFO si = { 0 };
    si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    CreateProcess(L"c:\\windows\\system32\\notepad.exe", 
        0, 0, 0, 0, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, 0, 0, &si, &pi);

    while (WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, 1000))
    {
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now the thread should terminate once the program exits. Notice "notepad.exe" will not terminate. You have to use the handle from `pi.hProcess` and close it from `main`.

Comment: @HarryJohnston it's just a test code, I changed it.

Comment: Thank you Barmak and Joachim for your help.  You got me pointed in the right direction.